# How to search table and return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of names and a column called is broke rules. If a person has broken a rule once, then their rule breaking status is yes  otherwise they are not a rule breaker. I know how I would do this programmatically in python or something, but how do I check their actual rule breaking status in excel?

| name | broke rule |
| --- | --- |
| bob | no |
| bob | no |
| jane | no |
| sam | yes |
| jane | yes |
| jake | no |
| bob | yes |
| paul | no |

The result I want

| name | broke rule | rule breaking status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | no | yes |
| bob | no | yes |
| jane | no | yes |
| sam | yes | yes |
| jane | yes | yes |
| jake | no | no |
| bob | yes | yes |
| paul | no | no |
| jake | no | no |

As you can see only jake and paul have a no status for their rule breaking, because they have not broken the rule once, while the others have broken a rule at least once before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"yes"),"yes","no")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel version is older than 2010 you can do:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$10=A2),--(B$2:B$10="yes"))=1,"yes","no")
```